# Nivo slider adjusting the height of the main image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, nivo-slider

I am trying to make a slider that is exactly a certain height, and needs 100% width. I have the width sorted, but when I have my height the slider adds something like 20px to the image. I know its not that big of a deal but it seems important for the project. All of the images I have are the exact height I want them to appear, so is there a way ether by changing something in the javascript or the addressing some id/class I haven't tried yet to change the height(and just the height)?

Thanks for your help.
Sorry but I am not allowed to release my code yet.

Comment: you dont have padding or border on you're code ?

Comment: no nothing around my slider at all other than the code from the nivo demo along with the default theme. I also changed the caption formatting a bit but I guess that this problem occurred before that

Comment: you can put a jsFiddle I can watch? just for slider

Comment: sorry I gave it a go but I couldn't get it working in fiddle, I think its a little to large for a js fiddle

Comment: this it's responsive slider ? can you try "overflow:hidden" for you're image, the 20px more disappear ?

Comment: Yeah I think it is the responsive version. I just downloaded it no to long ago. I have tried that it doesn't work. The extra 20pxs isn't white space or anything it is just the image stretched to a that point. I was thinking maybe the image will not keep its quality with the 100% width and will stretch if it didn't perform some alorgithm so I want to stop this from happening and not have it change the height but have various widths I don't want to care about the image quality now.

Comment: yes, if slider is responsive, the image can lost or win Xpx.. :D, if responsive run with jquery i dont know how remove it, but if is .css, check if you find background-size:cover; and delete it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really fix it but I found a workaround. I took off the bottom 20 or so px from my images and found that re sizes appropriately this takes away some info but hopefully it will be ok, here's to hoping the boss will like it!